# IS there another option for readlink of OSX?

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I'm trying to rename and tar files in a directory. I have a script that I was using on linux, but `readlink -f` does not work with OSX.

Is there an alternative I can use to what I'm doing below?

```sh
pathname=$(readlink -f $dirname)
cd $pathname/..
tar -zcf $dirname.tgz $pathname
rm -rf $pathname
```

Comment: You should make up your mind, whether you want a solution for bash or for zsh. You used both tags. For zsh, you could do a `pathname=$dirname:A`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `realpath` that is resolving all symlinks

Note: you should not use `cd` without testing if successful, otherwise your script may run on unexpected folder. `rm -rf` could be harmful too, you could use find for deleting folder. guess you don't want folder deleted when `tar` was running out of disk space or not successful due other reasons

```
pathname="$(realpath "$dirname")"
cd "${pathname%/*}" || exit 2
tar -zcf "${dirname##*/}.tgz" "${pathname##*/}" || exit 2
find "$pathname" -delete
```

check the string manipulation with echo to figure out what it does

```
echo "${pathname%/*}"
echo "${pathname##*/}"
```